# DB Functional Dependencies.

Tags: database, functional-dependencies

I understand the concept of functional dependencies in Databases, but when it comes down to a format like this, I can't seem to wrap my head around it.

```
**Relation:**
A  B  C
a1|b1|c1
a2|b1|c1          
a1|b2|c2
a1|b1|c2
a3|b2|c1
a2|b1|c2
```

Which functional dependencies exist in this relation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functional dependencies hold in/apply to a database *DESIGN*.

They do not "exist in a relation".  It could be said of a relation that it *SATISFIES* some [set of] functional dependencies, but it is meaningless and confused to say that a functional dependency "exists in a relation".

As Victor more or less pointed out, your example relation satisfies only the trivial FD {ABC} -> {ABC}.

As for your other question, "what normal form is this relation in", once again this question is completely meaningless and confused, because the property of "being in some normal form", applies *only to a design*, not to some particular relation value.  In relational terms : only a relation *variable* can be in some normal form, depending on which FDs are suppposed to hold in it, but a relation *value* cannot have such a property.

So, assuming that you are indeed talking of [the declaration of] a relation *variable* with a heading {A B C}, in which there are no nontrivial FDs (i.e. only {ABC} -> {ABC} holds), this relation variable is at least in BC normal form.

If there are no join dependencies, then your relvar is also in sixth normal form (no that's not a counting error).

Answer (score 0):

There are none.

A functional dependency implies that, after eliminating any duplicates involving both the dependent and determinant columns, you can stick an `UNIQUE` onto the determinant columns. For instance, `UNIQUE(A,B)` does not work because `a1,b1` appears twice, `UNIQUE(A,C)` fails because `a1,c2` appears twice, and `UNIQUE(B,C)` fails because `b1,c1` appears twice.

Comment: Thanks, that clears things up. But in what Normal Form would you say this relation is in?